# Nestjs dependency injection order when a module depends on a Mongoose model from @nestjs/mongoose, detailed diagram inside

Tags: node.js, nestjs-providers, nestjs-mongoose

The diagram does a good job at explaining the flow I currently have and why that is failing.

- I have `logger.module` that exports a `loger.service` that depends on a `@nestjs/mongoose` `LogModel`.
- I have a `db.module` that exports `session.service` and imports `logger.module`.
- I have a `session.service` that is exported by the `Db.Module` and imports `logger.service`
- I have a `mock.db.module` that is exactly like the real `db.module` (no mocked services, the real one) except the mongoose connection is to a in-memory mongodb.
- I have a `session.service.spec` tests file that imports `mock.db.module`

However, I can't find any good way of providing `LogModel`into `log.module` that doesn't need me to import `@nestjs/mongoose`and instantiate/wait for a new connection on every startup.

I was only able to produce 2 results:

- use `@forwardRef(() => Logger.module.register())` or/and `@forwardRef(()=> Db.module.register())` which causes heap allocation error
- don't use forwardRef and get circular dependency warnings.

How can I effectively map dependencies in an efficient way with Nestjs for this use case?

Diagram:

[image]